# How to keep the value when using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I am recently solving a leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/employee-importance/

I am also attaching the question below:

You are given a data structure of employee information, which includes the employee's unique id, his importance value and his direct subordinates' id.

For example, employee 1 is the leader of employee 2, and employee 2 is the leader of employee 3. They have importance value 15, 10 and 5, respectively. Then employee 1 has a data structure like [1, 15, [2]], and employee 2 has [2, 10, [3]], and employee 3 has [3, 5, []]. Note that although employee 3 is also a subordinate of employee 1, the relationship is not direct.

Now given the employee information of a company, and an employee id, you need to return the total importance value of this employee and all his subordinates.

Example 1:

Input: [[1, 5, [2, 3]], [2, 3, []], [3, 3, []]], 1
Output: 11
Explanation:
Employee 1 has importance value 5, and he has two direct subordinates: employee 2 and employee 3. They both have importance value 3. So the total importance value of employee 1 is 5 + 3 + 3 = 11.

I used this testcase:
Input: [[1,5,[2,3]],[2,3,[4,5]],[3,4,[]],[4,6,[]],[5,1,[]]], 1

Below is my code:

```cpp
/*
// Employee info
class Employee {
public:
    // It's the unique ID of each node.
    // unique id of this employee
    int id;
    // the importance value of this employee
    int importance;
    // the id of direct subordinates
    vector<int> subordinates;
};
*/
class Solution {

        int subImportance(vector<Employee*> employees, vector<int> &_subordinates, int _i, int _count)
    {


            for(int _subid : _subordinates)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(employees[i] ->id == _subid)
                    {
                        _count = _count + employees[i] -> importance;

                        cout<<i<<" "<<_count<<" "<<_subid<<endl;

                       if(employees[i] -> subordinates.size() == 0)
                           break;
                        else
        subImportance(employees, employees[i] -> subordinates, i , _count);
                        }
                }
            }
            cout<<"mark"<<endl;
           return _count;  

    }
public:

    int getImportance(vector<Employee*> employees, int id) {


        int found;
        for(int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++)
        {
            if(employees[i] -> id == id)
            {
               found = i;
            }
        }

        int count = employees[found] -> importance;

        if((employees[found] -> subordinates).size() == 0 )

            return count;
        else
        {

            return subImportance(employees,  employees[found] ->subordinates, found, count);
        }
    }
};
```

The _count is accumulating itself with employees[i] -> importance properly when it goes through the branch 1->2->4->5, then it reaches the end of the loop of parent node 2 and jumps to node 3, but the accumulated value is not kept ( importance of ID 1 + 2+ 4 + 5), instead, it only keeps (1 + 2) then it adds the importance of 3 and return the value( I have printed out the values). I believe it is because the function reaches the end of the loop of parent 2 (2->4->5) and "return _cout" and when it jumps back to node 3 to finish the loop it somehow does not keep the value in recursion.

How do I update my code to keep the calculated values?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You *could* pass `_count` by reference, but why not just use `+=` as you do for the individual importance?  Then you should be able to drop the `_count` parameter entirely and just initialize it to 0 in each call.

Comment: Suspicious: You are not doing anything with the value returned from the recursive call to `subImportance`.

Comment: `int found;` -- Uninitialized.  Then what happens if that loop doesn't find the employee?  You then use this uninitialized value here: `int count = employees[found] -> importance;` -- *I believe it is because.* -- Install a compiler on your computer and debug your code.  Don't rely on a website's compiler.  You don't learn necessary debugging skills to diagnose the issues in your program.

Comment: Unrelated: A stroll through the code with a debugger to watch what's going on is often faster than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, coding like this: `for(int _subid : _subordinates) { for(int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++)`, unless there is some serious memoization going on, usually results in time-out errors on these websites.  A nested loop runs too slowly when given large datasets, and these questions are designed for you to think beyond the naive nested loop solution.